# Wrong disk Space showing

Tags: windows-7

My laptop is showing wrong disk space. When I right click on my C: disk, it shows in the "Properties" that it’s size on disk is 17 GB. But when I open the folder, and select all the folders in all and check the "Properties" now, it shows that it's size on disk is just 300 MB.
Can this be possible?

Comment: Wait for it to load. Normally as you leave it there the size increases as it updates the size, this can take a few minutes.

Comment: What folder is this? Whats there?

Answer (score 0):

You must have hidden files and folders there.

If you check folder properties - you see size of everything inside.

If you enter folder, select all and check properties - you will see size of selected folders and files. Hidden folders and files will be not included there.

You can configure Windows Explorer to show hidden files and folders:

[Show hidden files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7) (at windows.microsoft.com)

Comment: I'm not sure this is the whole explanation: 300MB of unhidden files seems far too small for a C: drive, assuming this is the system disc. Certainly the swap and hibernation files alone could take up a sizeable proportion of 17GB, depending on the amount of RAM. But I would still expect several GB in unhidden files, even with very few extra programs and user data.

Comment: @AFH yea, but I'm not sure if he is talking about Windows folder.

Comment: But if it's _not_ the system drive, then I would not expect significant numbers of hidden files and folders.